# How can i setup IP whitelisting functionality for my API's?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, ip, whitelist

I have multiple node js API running on my aws VM's. These api are consumed on mobile app, website. Now it will be consumed by third party as server to server calling. I want to introduce IP whitelisting feature so authentic servers can make calls but i want api public also for mobile and website. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: So you want your API to be accessible for "everyone, and those servers too". Who, then, should be prevented from using your API?

Comment: I want api to be accessible by clients like browser or mobile apps but for server to server calling i want to apply some restrictions

Comment: That's going to be a problem, because you cannot tell whether an HTTP client is a "server". You could provide a token to your web applications, and those apps could "verify" themselves using that token, but then it'd have to be publicly-accessible to the browser - so a server could just copy it (via Web scraping) and pretend to be your web app. What you're trying to do is impossible because it entails having an API public (to Web clients) and non-public at the same time.